# How to give an argument Class<?> to Class<A>

Tags: java

In the following code, I analyze a given package to get all classes annotated with a given Annotation.

I want to load them into a Map with their annotation (and its value).

```
package com.test

@Named("valueToStock")
public class Main {
    @SneakyThrows
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static  ImmutableMap<Class<? extends Annotation>, Class<?>> find(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation, String packageBase) {
        final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        return ClassPath.from(loader).getTopLevelClassesRecursive(packageBase).stream()
                .filter(x -> x.load().getAnnotation(annotation) != null)
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors
                        .toMap(x -> x.load().getAnnotation(annotation), x-> x.load()), ImmutableMap::copyOf));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        find(Named.class, "com.test")
            .forEach((x, y) -> System.out.println(String.format("Class: %s, Annotation: %s", y, x)));
    }
}
```

My problem: when I try to call `x.load().getAnnotation(annotation);`

[image]

I tried removing `extends Annotation`, it does not work and I don't find other ways.

**EDIT:**
Also tried with

```
public static <A extends Annotation> ImmutableMap<Class<A>, Class<?>> find(Class<A> annotation, String packageBase) {
    final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    return ClassPath.from(loader).getTopLevelClassesRecursive(packageBase).stream()
            .filter(x -> x.load().getAnnotation(annotation) != null)
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors
                    .toMap(x -> x.load().getAnnotation(annotation), x-> x.load()), ImmutableMap::copyOf));
}
```

And still have the following error (same on compiling):

[image]

**EDIT:**
After have solved my problem, I noticed another mistake. The annotation instance has to be the value of map, and not the key ;) Pce

Comment: Please include the entire compiler error as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: `getAnnotation()` returns an instance of annotation, while your map requires the annotation's class. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to introduce a named type variable. Otherwise the compiler has no way of knowing that the two wildcard types are supposed to be the same type.

For example:

```
public static <T extends Annotation>
    ImmutableMap<Class<T>, Class<?>> find(
        Class<T> annotation, String packageBase) {
```

**Edit**: You're also confusing annotation *types* with annotation *instances*. `Class.getAnnotation(Class<A>)` returns `A`, not `Class<A>`.

You probably want to return a map keyed by annotation instances (e.g. `ImmutableMap<A, Class<?>>`). If you really want `Class<A>` objects as the keys, then you don't need `getAnnotation`. Just use `x.load().hasAnnotation(annotation) ? annotation : null` or something equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer, but I still have the same error (not a IDE bug, cause I can't compile)

Comment: @Romain: you need to provide the *entire* compiler error as *text*, not an image. You've clipped out essential information.

Comment: Intellij auto-compile and shows the error. I have the same given by the compiler:    _Error:(20, 25) java: incompatible types: inference variable K has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.lang.Class<A>
    lower bounds: A_

Comment: @Romain: That's still not the whole error message, but it's better. See my edit where I believe I have the answer to your problem. For future reference, with compiler errors, it's better to create a [mcve] which you can compile from the command line (using `javac` directly if possible). Then you can provide the *complete* compiler output in your question.

Comment: Nice edit, you got it. I want to get the annotation instance and then have its content. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just made a mistake, the annotation should be the value, and not the key of the map ;)